# Problem when accessing variables in Storage geth

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, storage

I found some contract that looks like this:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.2;
contract IceCream {
    address a;
    address b;
    bool public c = false;
    uint256 public d;

constructor(...){...}
}
```

I would now expect to get the following values when calling the following on my geth console:

```
await web3.eth.getStorageAt(address, 0) --> a
await web3.eth.getStorageAt(address, 1) --> b
await web3.eth.getStorageAt(address, 2) --> c
await web3.eth.getStorageAt(address, 3) --> d
```

Position **0**: I find **a** (Which I also suspect to be there).

Position **1**: I find **b** (Which I also suspect to be there).

Position **2**: I find some value 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a36 which i suppose is the value of the uint256 **d**. WHY?

Position **3**: I find:
0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000. WHY?

I thought the variables in storage are stored in order.

What am I missing here?

Probably it is something really easy and stupid but I just can`t make any sense of this.

Answer (score 1):

Each storage slot has a size of 256 bits (or 32 bytes). If several **elementary types** can be packed into 32 bytes they will use the same slot.

Let's see what we have here :

- `address a` : 20 bytes.

It is stored on slot 0 and `web3.eth.getStorageAt(address, 0)` returns the value of `a` (0 in your case as it was not instantiated).

- `address b` : 20 bytes

Since slot 0 has only 12 bytes left, `b` is stored on slot 1.

- `bool public c = false` : 1 byte

Booleans only occupy 1 byte. Hence `c` can be packed with `b` on slot 1. `web3.eth.getStorageAt(address, 1)` therefore returns `0x00 + b`.

This example is not very instructive as `0x00 + b` = `b` (on 32 bytes), that's why I advise you to deploy the same contract on whatever testnet setting `c` to `true`. You will then get `0x01 + b` on slot 1.

- `uint256 public d` : 32 bytes

It uses slot 2 and `web3.eth.getStorageAt(address, 2)` returns `d`

- Slot 3 is not used and therefore `web3.eth.getStorageAt(address, 3)` gives 0.